# Convert Probability of Landing in Range to Log Normal Probability Distribution

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution, range

I am working on a dataset that shows the probability of the FOMC Fed Funds Rate being in a specific range after a future FOMC meeting. The probability is based on a log-normal distribution (bounded by 0). For each meeting date I have 1 to many data points to work from. The values of the probability ranges sum to 1 for each meeting.

I need to find a formula that would allow me to convert the probabilities of landing in the range to a Mean and Standard Deviation value that I can use to calculate CDF and PDF values over a lognormal distribution. The goal is to be able to create a log-normal probability visualization for each meeting date.

The data I have to work with looks like this;

```
Meeting     Probability     Target_Range
2/1/2017    0.96            50-75
2/1/2017    0.04            75-100
3/15/2017   0.747428571     50-75
3/15/2017   0.243714286     75-100
3/15/2017   0.008857143     100-125
5/3/2017    0.57165399      50-75
5/3/2017    0.36217399      75-100
5/3/2017    0.064089064     100-125
5/3/2017    0.002082956     125-150
6/14/2017   0.281429657     50-75
6/14/2017   0.468525375     75-100
6/14/2017   0.215424488     100-125
6/14/2017   0.03356298      125-150
6/14/2017   0.001057501     150-175
```

Comment: Questions about how to use Excel (or any software--this isn't a software support site) are generally off topic here. I would also suspect that Excel is a poor choice, but that's a different issue.

Comment: Sorry about the reference to excel, I will change that. But the question is about how to convert a probability of landing in a range to a Mean and Standard Deviation. Excel is just the tool I need to do it in for this specific project.